# multiple text views or one text view with clickable spans?

Tags: android

I have an array of models each representing a word in a text. It looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Word> text;

class Word {
    public String name;
    public boolean isPunctuationMark;
```

I need to render that text inside an activity. What I also need to do is when a word is long-clicked I need to trigger and event and show a dialog with information specific to the selected word.

There are two approaches that I can use:

1. use one `TextView` widget per word
2. use one `TextView` to hold entire text but make each word a `ClickableSpan`

I've started implementing the second approach but there is no native support for `longClick` event on clickable spans, so I'd have to implement it myself. Also, it seems at the first glance that highlighting text and background of selected words is easier done with `TextViews` rather than with `ClickableSpans`. So now I'm thinking about trying out the first approach. Is there something I've missed when exploring these approaches? Maybe there's a third more architecturally correct option that is easier to implement supporting long-clicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use one `TextView` as this is a much more efficient UI. When there is a request for a `ViewGroup` to measure all of it's children, it is much faster to measure only one than a couple of thousand.

I have found a nice library you may try to use [here](https://github.com/qwerfrewq/textview_touch_word_select). It uses [getOffsetForPostion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getOffsetForPosition(float,%20float)) method added to `TextView` in API level 14.

> public int getOffsetForPosition (float x, float y)
>
> Added in API level 14 Get the character offset closest to the
>   specified absolute position. A typical use case is to pass the result
>   of getX() and getY() to this method.
>
> Parameters x  The horizontal absolute position of a point on screen
>   y The vertical absolute position of a point on screen Returns the
>   character offset for the character whose position is closest to the
>   specified position. Returns -1 if there is no layout.

Comment: thanks! :) Since I have `ArrayList<Word> text;` array of word models, I guess I'll have to find the model for the selected word comparing text in a model and selected word, and probably surrounding words too, right? Any idea of how to make that process efficient?

Comment: You can modify the library to return the number of the word and then you just get the element with that index from the array list... arraylist is good for getting stuff out of it. Assuming you will be displaying the words in the same order that you have them in your ArrayList

Comment: yeah, that's an idea, let me try it out and I'll get back :). Thanks!