# Is it possible to catch child events on parent views in android

Tags: android

In web development we have something called `event delegation` - when a parent DOM element receives all events of its children. This is mostly done for performance reasons. Does android have anything like that? For example, I have `LinearLayout` and 100 child `TextView`s. I don't wan't to add 100 event listeners to each `TextView`, but add just one to `LinearLayout` and catch events in it?

For example, instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {}
    });

    layout.addView(tv);
}
```

do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    layout.addView(tv);
}

layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // how to know here whether `v` is an instance of TextView or LinearLayout?
    }
});
```

Comment: do you want to capture touch events of child events and pass it to parent view?

Comment: this is part of a task I'm trying to accomplish and it's described in my [this quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011839/multiple-text-views-or-one-text-view-with-clickable-spans)

Comment: there is already method v instanceOf TextView which will return true or false.

Comment: Read this http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/

Comment: And this http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Comment: @BojanKseneman. thanks, I'll take a look at those, but I guess what you're saying is that this concept is not popular in android, correct?

Comment: I am saying that it would take me too long to make a decent looking answer... but why would I bother if you have answers with images and stuff on google's site and the other one. After reading for a while, you will notice that it depends on what a boolean value you return in certain cases, the event is propagated further on. If you return true, this means that you handled and should not be propagated any further

Answer (score 0):

you can implement `onClickListener` on Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // your oncreate
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // v is clicked textview
    }
}
```

make sure your textviews are clickable `textView.setClickable(true);`