# Show text words one after another but restrict with screen width

Tags: android

I have a text with words being rendered as `TextView`'s widgets - each word has its own `TextView` widget. I want them placed one after another but collapse when width of the screen is reached:

```
------------------------------
|Some words in this text are |
|not really                  |
|                            |
```

Currenly, If I use `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation they go like this:

```
------------------------------
|Some words in this text are | not really 
|                            |
|                            |
```

If I use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation they go like this:

```
------------------------------
|Some                        |
|words                       |
|in                          |
```

Comment: Why are you not displaying all words in a single textview?

Comment: [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011839/multiple-text-views-or-one-text-view-with-clickable-spans) my question that describes the task I'm currently doing, and I'm implementing the first approach I've come up there

Comment: @BojanKseneman, can you please comment anything about my question in the previous comment? I'm trying to implement interface for reading texts similar to kindle of Amazon, but struggle with correct approach

Comment: I have posted an answer to point you in the direction I would be going to try and solve this problem. I have never used any of those solutions, but they both provide some sort of doc and examples to help you out... Should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will need a FlowLayout whose custom implementation is given on this link

**Courtesy : Nishant Nair**

http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

Or this one, the more modern version https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look and try to use them. I'm also thinking maybe it'd be easier to go with `ClickableSpan`s? It seems that there are limitations for both approaches that I outlined in my other quesion and both would require not standard functionality.

Comment: I agree both solutions are not standard, but nor is your problem. Usually people are selecting a sequence of words - sentences, not a single word. I have never tried ClickableSpans, but this way I think it is more efficient as you only have one View.

Comment: Unfortunately there's almost no information on the web about `ClickableSpan`s, and even the book I'm reading from `CommonsWare` of more than 3000 pages doesn't mention them. I'm trying to implement native application of [my web service](http://inreado.com/#/read/102) where people do select individual words to get translations and I have amazon's kindle native app design in mind.

Comment: If you are targeting api level14+ you could use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getOffsetForPosition%28float,%20float%29 it will return a character offset to where the user clicked and you then find the word it belongs to and get the translation

Comment: Yes, I'm targeting API's 17+, I'll take a look. Maybe, if you have time, you could answer my other question about approaches and elaborate a bit on the approach you're suggesting with `getOffsetForPosition`. Also, just posted new question about the custom dialog [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014498/set-textview-tex-on-the-custom-dialog-created-through-dialogfragment). Maybe you could help if you have time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will take a look when I get home

Comment: I've tried the second layout from your link and it worked great. Thanks a lot! I've also just found out that `TextView` doesn't support text justification, which is really weird. It seems that one should go at great length to make a simple looking reading app like Amazon's kindle. Often times it's recommended to use `WebViews` and now I see why.

Comment: I know, WebView isn't perfect either... When you start doing advanced things with it, you get a headache :) If you have loads and loads and loads of words, use RecyclerView. About the book from CommonsWare, it's digital?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm quite good with web development and I already have created [hybrid application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inreado.beta) with cordova, I just thought I might give native app a shot. Yes, the book is digital, I bought a subscription for $45 [here](https://commonsware.com/). The author has something around 400k repution here on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I also think that this idea with multiple TextViews each for one word is not the best idea :)))... I'll try to implement approach with `getOffsetForPosition` tomorrow, yet don't have clear picture of how I'll go about it.

Comment: Copy paste this :D https://github.com/qwerfrewq/textview_touch_word_select/blob/master/TextViewTouchSelectWord/app/src/main/java/com/example/olaf/myapplication/MyActivity.java

Comment: That's a good suggestion I think, thanks a lot! :). I think I'll need to replace touch listener with LongClick listener and maybe make a few tweaks. I think you could post your suggestion to my question and I'd accept it, but probably asked a few more question there before accepting :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, i don't know if it will work for you but still i would like to share what worked for me.

1. **Set Max width** -first of all in TextView set max width eg- `android:maxWidth="size" android:singleline="false"`.(This would limit the no. of characters per line)
2. **Set layout width** to match parent rather than wrap content.
3. Also **remember to use dp for dimensions and sp for text size** so that your content is relative to display.
4. Always add a **linear layout in relative layout**.
5. Are you using an IDE like android studio? IDEs let you work graphically with the layout making it alot easier.

Comment: why would I need to set max length to limit number of chars? I want all characters to be shown

Comment: Should I set max-width for all TextViews? You're realizing that each word is in a separate TextView, right?

Comment: why is every word in different textview? are you trying do to something you haven't mentioned here yet?

Comment: please read my [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011839/multiple-text-views-or-one-text-view-with-clickable-spans) to understand

Comment: please edit your question to eliminate further confussion from what i understand you want something like float left as we have in html without view going out of screen?

Comment: Edited it. No, not like floats, just like normal flow where text items collapse when they reach the border of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try set TextView android:singleLine="false" and android:maxLines to some value.