# Set TextView tex on the custom dialog created through DialogFragment

Tags: android

I'm creating a dialog like this:

```
public class TextReaderDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private View form = null;

    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag, String customText) {
        super.show(manager, tag);

        // ---- form is not created here yet, so I get NullPointerException
        TextView tv = (TextView) form.findViewById(R.id.transcription);
        tv.setText(customText);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_reader_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.text_reader_dialog_title);
        builder.setView(form);
        return builder.create();
    }
```

And showing it from the activity like this:

```
new TextReaderDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "tag-string", "String to show");
```

The problem is that here:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) form.findViewById(R.id.transcription);
tv.setText(customText);
```

form is not yet available and points to null. How can I show the message passed from acitivity on the dialog?

Comment: Try to move your two lines into onCreateDialog() method. It seems like show() method is being called before onCreateDialog().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your argument via a `Bundle`.
Then you retrieve it in `onCreate`.
And you can use it in `onCreateDialog`.

Also you don't need a custom view for a simple text. You can display the text using `setMessage` from the `AlertDialog.Builder` class.

You can find an example in the documentation for [DialogFragment.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
int mNum;

/**
 * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
 * as an argument.
 */
static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
   }
   }
```

Comment: thanks, I'm adding arguments like this from the activity `new TextReaderDialog().setArguments(args).show(getFragmentManager(), "sample")`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom dialog and make a layout for it and then inflate it. With that you are able to control everything in that layout which is much more than Android stock dialogs offer. I have been using a custom dialog like this, all I really needed to call to show a custom message was `setProgressMessage` method

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends Dialog {


    private TextView text;
    private String textProgress;

    public CustomProgressDialog(Context _context, int resID) {
        this(_context, _context.getString(resID));
    }

    public CustomProgressDialog(Context _context, String txt) {

        super(_context);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
        }
        textProgress = txt;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom_progress_bar);
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);
        text.setText(textProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
    }

    public void setProgressMessage(String aText) {
        if (aText != null) {
            text.setText(aText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.cancel();
        Log.w("CustomDialog", "Dialog Cancelled");
    }

}
```

Make sure you supply the width of the dialog in your layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="0dp">
        <!-- Add stuff you need in your dialog here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I don't use custom dialogs because as I understand `CommonsWare` doesn't recommend using them giving the following reasons: _One challenge with dialogs comes with configuration changes, notably screen
rotations. If they pivot the device from portrait to landscape (or vice versa),
presumably the dialog should remain on the screen after the change. However, since
Android wants to destroy and recreate the activity, that would have dire impacts on
your dialog_.

Comment: And here is a bit more: _Pre-fragments, Android had a “managed dialog” facility that would attempt to help
with this. However, with the introduction of fragments came the DialogFragment,
which handles the configuration change process._

Comment: You need to save stuff you want to keep to your saveInstanceState... now if you have a custom View... it really doesn't matter DialogFragment up or down

Comment: sorry, didn't quite understand your last comment